# Suggested fliers for high school career fair?

Tags: student-motivation, secondary-education, careers

I will be tabling at a high school career fair and would like to have printed fliers about careers involving computer science. Does anyone know where I can find ones that are free (either to print or have sent to me)?

Comment: If this helps, I will post it as an answer. A question like this is pretty much limited to link-only answers, so it will be hard to formulate something. 
 httpss://findingada.com/resources/resources-for-schools/posters/

Answer (score 2):

All of the best fliers I found were at the [NCWIT website](https://www.ncwit.org/):

- [Computer science is for everyone](https://www.ncwit.org/sites/default/files/resources/microsoft_digitalskills_cs_toolkit_092018.pdf), pp. 13-16
- [Why Should Young People Consider Careers in Computing and Information Technology?](https://www.ncwit.org/resources/why-should-young-people-consider-careers-computing-and-information-technology) (also in [Spanish](https://www.ncwit.org/losjovenes))
- [Community College Pathway to IT and Computing Careers](https://www.ncwit.org/resources/community-college-pathway-it-and-computing-careers)
- [University Pathway to IT and Computing Careers](https://www.ncwit.org/resources/university-pathway-it-and-computing-careers)
- [Which computing pathway is right for me?](https://www.ncwit.org/resources/which-computing-pathway-right-me) (also in [Spanish](https://www.ncwit.org/node/5296))

Comment: Thanks for coming back with a response.  I'm sorry my link wasn't so helpful!  :)